# Picture doesn't show when compiling

Tags: includegraphics

I have problem, I use this code:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{hahaha.png}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\end{center}
```

But when I compile, the picture doesn't show.

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have draft mode on? Off-topic: do not use `\\ ` for new line.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I have draft mode on. I can fix it now, thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it got solved in the comments.

Comment: You're welcome! I see you've never accepted an answer to your previous questions: see here: [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852).